# How do I best force-flatten a (one dimensional) vector for N values?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, stdvector, allocator

I need something that behaves like an `std::vector` (interface/features/etc.) but I need it to be flat, i.e. it mustn't dynamically allocate a buffer. Clearly, this doesn't work in general, as the available size must be determined at compile time. But I want the type to be able to deal with `N` objects without additional allocations, and **only if further items are pushed** resort to dynamic allocation.

Some implementations of `std::vector` already do this, but only to the extent that it uses its existing members if the accumulated size of the content fits (I believe about three pointers-worth of payload). So, **firstly**, this is not a guarantee and **secondly** it is not configurable at compile time.

My thoughts are that I could either

- **A)** self-cook a type (probably bad because I'd loose the ridiculous performance optimisations from `vector`)
- **B)** use some sort of `variant<vector<T>,array<T,N>>` with an access wrapper (oh, the boilerplate)
- **C)** come up with a `MyAllocator<T,N>` that has an `array<T,N>` member which then may be used to hold the first `N` items and after this defer to `allocator<T>` but I'm not sure if this can work because I cannot find out whether `vector` must permanently hold an instance of its allocator type as a member (I believe it does not)

I figure I'm not the first person to want this, so perhaps there are already approaches to this? Some empirical values or perhaps even a free library?

Comment: Did you check [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)?

Comment: @TonyTannous `reserve` doesn't satisfy the requirements stated above.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want a `vector` with, effectively, Short String Optimization?

Comment: @bitmask Do you actually *need* this or are you just trying to achieve it? If you think you need it, this may be an X/Y problem.

Comment: @user4581301 That is another way to put it, yes. Only that the "chars" here can be quite a bit larger than one octet.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [folly/small_vector](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/small_vector.md) of use.

> folly::small_vector is a sequence container that
>   implements small buffer optimization. It behaves similarly to
>   std::vector, except until a certain number of elements are reserved it
>   does not use the heap.
>
> Like standard vector, it is guaranteed to use contiguous memory. (So,
>   after it spills to the heap all the elements live in the heap buffer.)

Simple usage example:

```
small_vector<int,2> vec;
vec.push_back(0); // Stored in-place on stack
vec.push_back(1); // Still on the stack
vec.push_back(2); // Switches to heap buffer.

// With space for 32 in situ unique pointers, and only using a
// 4-byte size_type.
small_vector<std::unique_ptr<int>, 32, uint32_t> v;

// A inline vector of up to 256 ints which will not use the heap.
small_vector<int, 256, NoHeap> v;

// Same as the above, but making the size_type smaller too.
small_vector<int, 256, NoHeap, uint16_t> v;
```

Comment: Cute! Also the size_type is a nice touch. I'll check it out.